# Hashchange html submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's a problem with my script. If I was to type something in with a spacebar, ie: **google map** it would change in input box: **google+map** what I don't like.
Also... When I submit again, it messes up more badly

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

--

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
    window.location.hash = form_data.replace('=','/');
    return false;
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    var values = window.location.hash.slice(1).split('/');
    $("[name=" + values[0] + "]").val(values[1]);
});

var values = window.location.hash.slice(1).split('/');
$("[name=" + values[0] + "]").val(values[1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to escape the value from the hash:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
    window.location.hash = form_data.replace('=','/');
    return false;
});

$(window).on('hashchange', updateVal);

updateVal();

function updateVal() {
   var values = window.location.hash.slice(1).split('/');
   $("[name=" + values[0] + "]").val(decodeURIComponent(values[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case FORM method 'GET' at `<form name="input" action="" method="get">` should not be used.
According to W3 recommendation [here](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#examples)

> 1.3 Quick Checklist for Choosing HTTP GET or POST
>
> Use GET if: The interaction is more like a question (i.e., it is a
>   safe operation such as a query, read operation, or lookup). Use POST
>   if: The interaction is more like an order, or The interaction changes
>   the state of the resource in a way that the user would perceive (e.g.,
>   a subscription to a service), or The user be held accountable for the
>   results of the interaction.

In the GET the data is sent in URI and there is no `spaces` in URI and hence the problem.

However, if you need to use GET request for this then use decodeURIComponent to `decodeURIComponent(values[1])` to escape the value